# how to add report rdlc image parameter to get the image from application settings?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my WinForms application, different users work on the application. Each user, uses it's own logo and name that I store it in app settings. Now, I want to display the app settings image on the reports. I have googled it, as per my search no one talks about this way. Here is what I found and tried it:

```
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
 string imgFrom = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.system_img).AbsolutePath;
 ReportParameter parameter = new ReportParameter("img", imgFrom);
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
```

Before this, I have added a parameter to the report. But this doesn't work in my case.
Any can tell me how to do this?

Comment: The server does not have access to the users local folder.  Either you have to send the image as a parameter or you have to put the images in a folder where the SQL server can access the files like on a Network folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing the code and made two changes in the above code, it works just fine. Here are the changes:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
string imgFrom = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.system_img).AbsoluteUri; // changed from AbsolutePath to AbsoluteUri
                        ReportParameter rpImg = new ReportParameter("img", imgFrom);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp1, rp2, rpImg }); // add the parameter to another set of parameters that I had before.
```